# Is C++ pointer aliasing a threat if the pointers are exactly the same?

Tags: c, pointers, restrict, restrict-qualifier

Consider this function intended for vectorization:

```
void AddSqr(float* restrict dst, float* restrict src, int cnt)
{
    for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++) dst[i] = src[i] * src[i];
};
```

This would work if the src & dst are not aliased of course. But what if src == dst? Extreme cases such as src == dst+1 are not allowed of course. But if the pointers are the same, there shouldn't be a problem, or am I missing something?

Edit: restrict is Intel C++ compiler keyword, MSVC has __restrict.

My point with this question is that I don't see a way how any kind of vectorization could go wrong: Since every dst value is dependent on the single src value at either completely different (without any aliasing) or EXACTLY the same address, when dst is changed, the src value will never be needed anymore, because the fact that it has been written means that the output has been calculated. The only case would be if the compiler used the dst itself as temporary buffer, which I don't think is even correct.

Comment: I think [Can you use restrict-ed pointers to access the same object in some cases?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18059205/1708801) answers your question

Comment: Isn't this a C question? C++ doesn't have `restrict`.

Comment: I do not know C, but under my reading of the standard, the above is UB.  The compiler is free to emit pathological code that assumes `a[7]` is never changed, even after `b[7]` is written to.  Is there a reason to emit that code?  No, but still valid output.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the tags to C, since `restrict` is not a C++ keyword. OP, if you disagree, re-tag it back, but please also edit in an explanation how you're using a C functionality in C++.

Comment: restrict is actualy Intel C++ specific keyword, MSVC has _restrict instead (but I think it accepts restrict too).

Comment: `restrict` is a type qualifier in C11. [Draft n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

In C, your code causes undefined behaviour by violating the `restrict` definition because it writes to one object through `dst` but reads the same object through `src`.

It doesn't matter whether or not there is an offset between `dst` and `src`; the condition is that there exists a `float` object which is written through one pointer and read through the other.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict is a keyword to allow some optimisations that are only valid if the two pointers don't interfere with each other.

For your very simple case it's unlikely that there are any optimisations available that will fail when the two pointers are identical so when you test nothing bad will happen.

But in the more general case the `restrict` keyword means you are asserting that the two pointers are different and the data structures that they point to are distinct. The compiler is free to use this assertion to allow any optimisation it wants, especially ones that will make your program fail catastrophically if your assertion is not true.

This failure is called 'undefined behaviour' because the C standard does not define what happens when the assertion is wrong. As this is an optimisation assertion completely unpredictable behaviour, commonly referred to as "nasal demons", is reasonable behaviour for the C compiler to define.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers folks. So:
- By standard C++ definition this is really incorrect.
- However I got reply directly from Intel that this is ok.

My original question indeed was not about if it "follows the rules", but if there is a possibility that it could go wrong. The src/dst arrays are mapped 1:1, so either the arrays are completely different, or they are exactly the same, hence each item is either dependent on some completely unrelated item, or itself. Therefore if the item is rewritten, its final value has been computed stored and will never be needed again during the cycle.

Anyways I did some additional processing:

```
void AddSqr(float* restrict dst, float* restrict src, int cnt)
{
    if (dst == src)
        for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++) dst[i] = dst[i] * dst[i];
    else
        for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++) dst[i] = src[i] * src[i];
};
```

This should fix the potential problem and even provides some additional optimization possibilities, as in the case the pointers are the same, the compiler can use just one register (or don't use offset register) to target the arrays.