# Can I subtract or compare restricted pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, restrict

## Question:

If I have two pointers (essentially a `begin` and an `end`) which are qualified with `restrict`. The `begin` pointer is used for dereferencing/reading, and the `end` pointer is a one-past-the-end pointer that is never dereferenced and is only used to check the size of the range (via `end - begin`). Once the range is consumed I expect `begin` and `end` to be equal and `end - begin` to be 0, though at this point the two pointers will never be dereferenced.

Given `restrict`'s restrictions on pointers, is it well-defined behavior to subtract and compare these two pointers?

## MVCE:

I have some code like the following:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct Reader {
  const char* restrict data;
  size_t size;
};

char read_char(struct Reader* reader) {
  --reader->size;
  return *reader->data++;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct Reader reader = {
    .data = argv[1],
    .size = argv[1] ? strlen(argv[1]) : 0,
  };

  if (reader.size > 0) {
    return read_char(&reader);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'd like to change it so that instead of having to modify both `data` and `size` when reading, only `data` needs to be modified:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct Reader {
  const char* restrict data;
  const char* restrict end;  // Not sure if this should be restrict or not.
};

char read_char(struct Reader* reader) {
  return *reader->data++;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct Reader reader = {
    .data = argv[1],
    .end = argv[1] + (argv[1] ? strlen(argv[1]) : 0),
  };

  if (reader.end - reader.data > 0) {  // Is this okay?
    return read_char(&reader);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Is this permissible, given `restrict`'s restrictions on pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use restrict-ed pointers to access the same object in some cases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059205/can-you-use-restrict-ed-pointers-to-access-the-same-object-in-some-cases)

Comment: @LPs: My question is different. I'm not trying to access the same object via aliased pointers. The `end` pointer is never dereferenced, and the only time `data` and `end` alias is when they're equal (at which point dereferencing either would be undefined behavior anyway). My question is about comparing the two pointers, which is different.

Comment: Into proposed duplicate is shown that as far as you do not modify the pointed object the behavior is defined.  Probably I'm missing something...

Comment: Note `.end = argv[1] + (argv[1] ? strlen(argv[1]) : 0)` is odd.  I'd expect `.end = (argv[1] ? argv[1] + strlen(argv[1]) : argv[1])`.  Your code begets the question "Is it OK to add 0 to `NULL`" (possible a good SO question).   Suggest avoiding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: your usage is permissible by my reading of the standard.

The standard's requirements for use of `restrict`-qualified pointers all have to do with aliasing and access to the pointed-to object.  I find no limitations on using such pointers as operands of the pointer difference operator (`-`), and such restrictions would not be consistent with the purpose of `restrict` (which is to provide greater opportunities for optimization).

In contrast, a pointer value obtained from a `restrict`-qualified pointer by addition of an integer is "based on" the original pointer in a sense that is significant to the standard.  Roughly, it is acceptable to access the pointed-to object via such a pointer, whereas it is not acceptable to access that object via a pointer to the same object that is not "based on" the restricted pointer.

Additionally, I don't think `Reader.end` needs to be `restrict`-qualified, and I don't think such qualification helps you at all.  However, you must ensure that neither `Reader.end` nor any pointer derived from it is used to access the data; you must use only `Reader.data` for that.  In `main()`, too.
On the other hand, pretty much all that is moot if you nowhere modify the pointed-to object.

Comment: Both clang and gcc are prone to behave nonsensically if a `restrict`-qualified pointer is compared to a pointer that is not derived from it.  I don't think anything in the Standard was intended to allow such weirdness, but I doubt the authors of clang or gcc will ever allow the definition of `restrict` to be adjusted to forbid it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the Standard or rationale suggests any intention to forbid comparisons or computations on restrict-qualified pointers.  The way the Standard defines the notion of one pointer being "based upon" another, however, interacts weirdly with comparisons.  For example, given something like:

```
int test(int *restrict p, int *q, int i)
{
  p[i] = 1;
  if (p+1 == q)
    p[1] = 2;
  return p[i];
}
```

Replacing `p` with a pointer to a copy of the identified array would prevent the assignment to `p[1]`, making unanswerable the question of whether such replacement would affect the address used in that assignment.  While it would seem obvious that `p[1]` is based upon `p`, and it would seem absurd that the comparison would affect that, neither clang nor gcc recognize the lvalue `p[1]` above as being based upon the same `p` as the lvalue `p[i]`.